# javascript to get php variable doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<div id="div01">01</div>
<div id="div02">02</div>
<img src="../img/logo.png" onclick="blueSky()"/>
```

js

```
function blueSky() {
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url: 'test.php',
success: function(respond) { 
  document.getElementById("div02").innerHTML=respond;  // works
}
});
$("#div01").html("<?php echo $target;?>"); }   // should be "abc" - doesn't work
```

test.php

```
...    
$target = "abc";
```

Comment: Isn't it `.innerHTML` not `.html`?

Comment: Check the source code in your browser. Do you see the line `$("#div01").html("abc");`?

Comment: When you look at the page source with "View Source" under the browser, does it render correctly?

Comment: What file is the JS in? Seems to me like you are loading test.php via ajax and then trying to get a php variable from it, that is not possible.

Comment: As a side-note, if you are using jQuery to select elements than don't have a JavaScript getElementById in the middle of it. That can get very confusing. Sure sometimes JavaScript is better cause it is faster like most for loops are but when selecting elements stick with on or the other within the same function at least.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to access the variable from `test.php` in the javascript?  That's not possible . . . you'll need to use the callback and access the return values

Comment: @Fluffeh - JavaScript: `.innerHTML`, jQuery: `.html`.

Comment: Like @ernie said - you can't make an ajax call and expect you can see the variables from the other file.

Comment: You can use `include`, see my answer.

Comment: So what exactly is the goal here? Are you trying to get 2 different contents from test.php in one call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#div01").html("<?php echo $target;?>"); }   // should be "abc" - doesn't work
```

It is not supposed to work. Because `$target` is defined in test.php and is not within the scope of where you have the javascript `.html()` call.

You can do:

```
$("#div01").html(respond);
```

inside the `success:` attribute of your ajax call.

Also, in test.php, I hope you are doing an `echo $target` in order to get "abc" pushed back into the `respond` object of `blueSky()` function

Comment: And of course let `test.php` echo the variable: `echo $target;`.

Comment: @Birk I was just adding that :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using AJAX to get `test.php`, so you will either have to do this:

**test.php**

```
$target = 'abc';
echo $target;
```

or this:

```
function blueSky() {
<?php include 'test.php'; ?>
$("#div01").html("<?php echo $target; ?>"); }
```